# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with im getting a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on a new server.

And im bit of a noob on .htaccess, and i have used the generator on http://searchfriendlyurls.com to make my .htaccess.

my .htaccess looks like:

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(img|uploads)($|/) - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^thenight\.dk$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://thenight.dk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^book/([a-zA-Z]+)$ /index.php?page=book&id=$1 [L]
```

Anyone who can help me ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

it was a problem on the server...